# Exclude in regular expressions

Tags: java, regex, spring

I want to read files that do not contain `.temp` as an extension in a folder. I want to use a regular expression for this. How do you use exclusions in a regular expression to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This part tells to look for a specific array of chars: `[0-9]`. If you want to exclude it you just add a `^` (implies "not") in front of it. Like `[^0-9]` for "Not a number".

So, to answer your question you would have this inside your regular expression:

```
   ^((?!\.temp).)*$
```

This above regular expression will match any line that does not contain .temp

Answer (score 2):

Don't be bothered and just negate the test:

```
private static final Pattern NOTME = Pattern.compile("\\.temp$");

// in code

if (NOTME.matcher(input).find())
    // illegal!
```

But really, you should be using:

```
if (input.endsWith(".temp"))
    // illegal
```

Also, if you use Java 7, please ditch `File` and go with `Files` and `Path`.

Answer (score 0):

Know it's not regex, but for readability I'd use

```
!fileName.endsWith(".temp")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this, based on Java's FilenameFilter interface:

```
package dk.tbsalling;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FilenameFilter;

public class FileDemo {
   public static void main(String[] args) {

      File f = null;
      File[] paths;

      try{      
         f = new File("d:/tmp");

         FilenameFilter fileNameFilter = new FilenameFilter() {

            @Override
            public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
               return name.matches(".+(?<!\.temp)");
            }
         };

         paths = f.listFiles(fileNameFilter);

         for(File path:paths)
         {
            System.out.println(path);
         }
      }catch(Exception e){
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
}
```